# Asynchronous REST API inside Discord.py

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp, discord.py

I am looking for a way to integrate a REST API inside my `Discord.py`, using the rewrite branch. I want to use `aiohttp` to handle requests but I am unsure of which approach I should take. The objective is to make for example a GET request to the API that would return a list of guilds the bot is in. Or as another example, a POST request that would ask the bot to write a given message into a specific channel. Overall it's about giving instruction to the bot from a webpage.

I tried putting the aiohttp app router and runner inside my Discord.py client class. The web server is indeed running, I made an async function to return guilds the bot is in, but it looks like the function won't take the request argument I pass to it when going to `http://127.0.0.1/guilds`. Thus leading to a `missing 1 required positional argument` error.

```
import discord
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))

    async def get_guilds(self, request):
        response_obj = self.guilds
        return web.json_response(response_obj,status=200,content_type='application/json')

    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_get('/guilds', get_guilds)
    web.run_app(app, port=80)

client = MyClient()
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Besides, the aiohttp server does not run asynchronously. I expect the `on_ready(self)` to run, but it never does. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Your Discord client and web server should be two different objects.  Remove the server starting code from the server definition, and change `client.run` to `client.start` [as shown here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Client.run).  This prevents the discord client from blocking the event loop.  The code to start the server should come after that, and will also block the event loop.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  I'm sorry "The code to start the server should come after" you mean after client.start(TOKEN) ? If so I'm confused, how would the aiohttp server runs if not in the discord client loop ?

Also `client.start(TOKEN)`raise RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.start' was never awaited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I found a way.

### bot.py

```
from asyncio import gather, get_event_loop
from logging import basicConfig, INFO
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from aiohttp.web import AppRunner, Application, TCPSite
from sys import argv

from api import routes

basicConfig(level=INFO)

async def run_bot():

    app = Application()
    app.add_routes(routes)

    runner = AppRunner(app)
    await runner.setup()
    site = TCPSite(runner, '0.0.0.0', 8080)
    await site.start()

    bot = Bot(command_prefix="$")
    app['bot'] = bot

    try:
        await bot.start(TOKEN)

    except:
        bot.close(),
        raise

    finally:
        await runner.cleanup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run_bot())
```

### api.py

```
routes = RouteTableDef()

@routes.get('/guilds')
async def get_guilds(request):
    client = request.app['bot']
    guilds = []
    for guild in client.guilds:
        guilds.append(guild.id)

    response = Handler.success(guilds)
    return json_response(response, status=200, content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the below should work to run the two tasks together.  This isn't great design though, and will only get more complicated.  You may be better served by separating your bot and your server and using a more structured way of communicating between them than sharing memory.

```
import discord
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web

client = discord.Client()

async def on_ready():
    print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(client.user))

async def get_guilds(request):
    response_obj = client.guilds
    return web.json_response(response_obj,status=200,content_type='application/json')


try:
    bot_task = client.loop.create_task(client.start("token"))
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_get('/guilds', get_guilds)
    web.run_app(app, port=80)
except:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(client.logout())
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Oddly I cannot iterate into any client attributes. `local variable 'i' referenced before assignment` when trying to return. 

You mentioned a more structured way of communicating between the bot and the server than sharing memory.  What would that be ? Sockets ? Looping trough a file ?

Comment: There's no `i` in the code you provided.  Depending on how complicated your logic gets, it could be as simple as a shared database.